# To add up all values entered by a user to reach a specific sum

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, permutation

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[], partial_sum=0):
    if partial_sum == target:
        yield partial
    if partial_sum >= target:
        return
    for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
        remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
        yield from subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n], partial_sum + n)
    
list = [ ]
no=int(input("Enter the count of the List: "))
s=float(input("Enter the target value: "))
for c in range (1,no):
    temp=(input("Value "+str(c)+"= " ))
    list.extend(map(float, temp.split(", ")))
    
print(list)
subset_sum(list,s,no)
```

The objective of the program is to find all the possible combination to reach the specific target.
The problem is, it doesn't print the partial after finding the combinations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[], partial_sum=0):
    if partial_sum == target:
        yield partial
    if partial_sum >= target:
        return
    for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
        remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
        yield from subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n], partial_sum + n)
    
nums = [ ]
no=int(input("Enter the count of the List: "))
s=float(input("Enter the target value: "))
for c in range (1,no+1):
    temp=(input("Value "+str(c)+"= " ))
    nums.extend(map(float, temp.split(", ")))
    
print(nums)
print(list(subset_sum(nums,s)))
```

There were a few bugs in your program:

1. Generator objects don't produce data unless asked for. So, you need to extract them from the generator object by creating a list out of it or explicitly iterating over it. That's why I changed the last line to:

```
print(list(subset_sum(nums,s)))
```

2. It is never a good idea to name a `list`, `list`. In this case it would have overwritten `list` and my use of `list` on the last line wouldn't work. So, I changed it to `nums`.
3. In your original code you pass it `no` as the third argument of `subset_sum`. `no` is the length of `nums` (of type integer) while the third parameter of `subset_sum` is the partial result of type `list`. Since it has a default value we don't even need to pass in the third argument.
4. In your input routine, you loop from `1` to `no`. This would leave you one element short of the requested length of `nums` since the upper bound of a for loop is exclusive.